# Custom facet is not showing up in bucket search

Tags: sitecore, facet, sitecore7.2

I am using sitecore 7.2.

I have an item bucket and I have lots of items inside that bucket.
Now, the requirement is to add some custom facets in the search result view.

So, I went here: /sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Facets.
Copied the "Author" facet and rename it to "City". 
Changed the facet field to "city_t" (this is the field name in index).
enabled it.

But when i go to bucket search view, i don't see the new facet.
Am I missing something?

NOTE: I tried the same with Sitecore 8, and the facets shows up in the search result view.

But I have to do it in sitecore 7.